# How does the while loop works in this case?

Tags: c++, string, c++11

This code will print a string of characters:

```
const char* aString = "This is a string";
const char* ptrString = aString;
while(*ptrString)
{   std::cout << *ptrString;
    ptrString++;
}
```

I'm still a newbie. From what I had learnt so far, while loop always has a condition inside the bracket like while(x<10) or something. I just don't understand why does the while loop in this case has only *ptrString as its condition. What does it actually mean? Can somebody explain to me?

Comment: I'm not 100% convinced about closing as a C duplicate. In this case, C and C++ are the same. But if anyone thinks I should re-open, ping me in a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the pointer reaches the end of the string it finds an end of string character which value is 0, which evaluates to false when casting to bool. Then the loop ends.

Answer (score 1):

```
while(*ptrString)
```

It stops when the `*ptrString` is null character. As `ptrString` is incremented in `ptrString++;`, eventually `*ptrString` will point to null character.

You can simplify the loop body to

```
std::cout << *ptrString++; // Ideal use of post-fix operator
```

though..